Using recharts, how can I access the data I send through to use as conditional for each Bar in a BarChart?
Currently I have my BarChart setup as shown:
<BarChart
  data={response}
  margin={{
  top: 5,
  right: 40,
  bottom: 5,
  }}
>
  <Legend />
  <Tooltip offset={20} content={<LoadsBarChartTooltip />} />
  <YAxis
     domain={[0, 'dataMax + 1']}
     label={{
     value: 'Total Count',
     angle: -90,
     position: 'insideLeft',
     fontSize: '12px',
     }}
   />
   <XAxis
     dataKey="trailer_id"
     tick={{ fontSize: 8 }}
     name="Trailer ID"
   />

   <Bar
     stackId="a"
     dataKey="loaded_shipments"
     fill="#925abf"
     name="Loaded Shipments"
   />
   <Bar
     stackId="a"
     dataKey="overage_shipments"
     fill="#A2BDF8"
     name="Overages"
   />
   <Bar
     stackId="a"
     dataKey="shortaged_shipments"
     fill="#fdc6c6"
     name="Missing"
   />
</BarChart>

To my understaning, recharts maps your data to the bars internally. For each object in the data array (response), I have a 'state' variable that I want to use as a conditional for  properties such as stroke and strokeDasharray. I'm just unsure how I would be able to access that variable.
For more context, here is the data that is being sent through:
    export type GetLoadsRecievedWithAccuracyResponse = {
      trailer_id: string;
      accuracy: string;
      overage_shipments: string;
      loaded_shipments: string;
      shortaged_shipments: string;
      state: string;
    }[];

I've done some research but still can't find an answer. (It may not even be possible?)
